# How to launch my ASP.NET MVC app in a Coded UI Test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coded-ui-tests

Environment: ASP.NET MVC4, Visual Studio 2013

I want to write a Coded UI Test that tests my MVC app.  The first thing that the test needs to do is to launch my app (as though I had pressed Ctrl-F5).  This means that the coded UI test needs to:

1. Start IIS Express to host my app.
2. Navigate to `http://localhost:xxxx`, where `xxxx` is my app's current port number as hosted by IIS Express

I would assume that there is some magic baked into the CUIT framework that makes it easy to run the current app (as though I had pressed Ctrl-F5) as a "step" in my test, but I haven't found it yet.

So, to solve item 1, I've found The [Trackyon CUIT Helpers](http://donovanbrown.com/?tag=/Coded-UI-Test) NuGet package.

To solve item 2, I know that I can use this code to launch my website in a new browser window:

```
BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("http://localhost:4892"));
```

But I don't want to hard-code the port number. **How do I find my URL programmatically?**  Or, more generally, **what is the "correct" way to start my MVC app running in a browser window hosted by IIS Express during a Coded UI Test?**

Answer (score 1):

I know you were asking about was "as though I had pressed Ctrl-F5" so why not?

Coded ui can do a ctl f5 this way:

```
Keyboard.SendKeys("^{F5}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the SendKeys code example!  Of course, it only works if the VS IDE has focus; if I had multiple tests, and I used it at the start of each test, I'd only be assured that it would work at the start of the first test (assuming I manually interacted with the VS IDE to start the test).  When the first test completes, there is no guarantee that the IDE would regain focus...

Comment: You can interact with the IDE just like the application under test and either set focus directly, or click in the window.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do that, it would help if you explained why you want to do this.

I would recommend that you set up some sort of continuous integration process that automatically deploys the newest version of your web application and then runs the tests automatically.  I have a dedicated IIS server which hosts the latest version of each web application, it is automatically built by TeamCity when changes are committed to the version control and then deployed with Web Deploy to the IIS server, then it automatically builds the test suit and runs it against the newest version of the web application.

One reason this is better is that a part of the search conditions in the CUIT is usually the URI, but of course you could change them, however the tests are more valuable if they are testing a published version of the page, the closer you are to a real environment the better.

Comment: I want to do it this way because I spent 30 years developing real-time simulation software at Big Aerospace with an IT team wrapped around me, and now I'm a one-man-shop developing a complex website.  I've spent the last year learning a whole new alphabet soup of web development technology, which, I might point out, evolves faster than I can adopt it.  In my simple-minded "develop it/test it/deploy it" brain, it seems reasonable to run the UI test in my development environment the same way I run my unit tests.  I'm not eager to dig into yet another technology (CI).  Sigh...

Comment: It's obvious why Bob.at.SBS wants to do that. Run tests while coding on his Dev machine without needing to submit changes or setup automatic build

Answer (score 0):

I put in a 'Service Locator' pattern which provides URL for all services in your application from a configuration file. 
Then each developer in team can replace globally provided services with local versions. 
When tests run on your machine, they look at your IIS Express